# How to optimize query with multiple %

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, indexing

Please help me optimize my Mysql query below

```
SELECT * FROM `ticket` WHERE `ticket_id` LIKE '%wm%33%' LIMIT 0,1000
```

the table doesn't have full text index and i'm affraid that giving the column a full text index will cost time when table is needed to be always on

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: I don't feel that this question provides enough information. For example, what does the `ticket_id` data look like? Are you always searching in the same way? Could the IDs be broken down into separate columns and indexed to aid searching?

Comment: WIthout a full-text index you can't optimize a LIKE pattern that begins with `%`. Ordinary indexes are B-trees, they work from the beginning of the string. If the pattern doesn't have a fixed beginning, indexes can't be used and you have to do a full scan.

Comment: But if the parts of the ticket that you want to match are at fixed positions in the string, you could create virtual columns for them using `SUBSTR()`, and index that.

Comment: @Schwern I'm using Mysql version 8.0

Comment: @fubar the ```ticket_id``` have 3 characters that i replace with ```$```. I have tried to change ```%``` to triple underscore (```___```) but still get same time

Comment: @Barmar if i don't have fixed beginning, can it be optimized using full text index?

And about using SUBSTR(), can you tell me how to do it?

Comment: @hamzbond - post some representative sample data, and explain how/why you're searching with `wm` and `33`. We cannot offer appropriate solutions if we don't fully understand the context of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a full text index, and I would suggest you do some benchmarking to see if the index adversely affects insert performance, you can restructure your data to eliminate the need for those sort of searches.

We don't know what's in `ticket_id`, but it's clear it has some sort of structure. Rather than parsing and searching this amalgamation, it's better to pull it apart into its individual pieces and recombine them.

To use a similar example, let's look at email addresses. What if you want to search for users whose email addresses are for `gmail.com`? The naive way to do this would be...

```
create table users (
  id serial primary key,
  email varchar(255) not null unique
);

select * from users
where email like '%@gmail.com'
```

There's the performance problem. There's also the problem of matching `user@subdomain.gmail.com`. `like '%gmail.com'` brings its own problems, it will match `person@thingmail.com`.

Instead, using [generated columns](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-generated-columns.html) we can split the domain from the email address and index it.

```
create table users (
  id serial primary key,
  email varchar(255) not null unique,
  domain varchar(255) as (
    substring_index(substring_index(email, '@', -1), '.', -2)
  ),

  index(domain)
);
```

Now matching the domain is a simple indexed equality check.

```
select * from users
where domain = 'gmail.com'
```

I expect you can do something similar for your `ticket_id`. Whether this is worth the effort requires some benchmarking, and also a consideration for complexity: a full text index is simpler and more flexible.

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=194036c00070c13d64a9732562540d0a)

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE `ticket_id` LIKE '%wm%33%'
```

may be replaced with

<s>`WHERE LOCATE('wm', ticket_id) < LOCATE('33', ticket_id)`</s> (see below)

I think it is less expensive.

PS. None indexing may help to improve such search performance...

---

> **Barmar**: `LOCATE()` returns `0` if the string isn't found, so this will return rows that don't contain `wm`. Change it to
>
> `LOCATE('wm', ticket_id) BETWEEN 1 AND LOCATE('33', ticket_id)`

That's true.

Comment: `LOCATE()` returns `0` if the string isn't found, so this will return rows that don't contain `wm`. Change it to `LOCATE('wm', ticket_id) BETWEEN 1 AND LOCATE('33', ticket_id)`

Comment: Why should a non-sargable `LOCATE` be any faster than the `LIKE`?  Both have to read _every_ row and do un-indexable stuff.

Comment: @RickJames If LOCATE/INSTR are not mapped to LIKE/REGEXP they're less expensive... sometimes the saving for even promille may make sense.